# Not able to open emulator

Tags: android

When I start my emulator there comes only the window showing a text "android" like the one in the image attached which stays for hours. How can this be fixed?

[image: snapshot of the window]

Comment: where is the image?

Comment: @Yogendra can you please add some more details here about what issues you are experiencing. The link to the screen shot doesn't tell us much.

Comment: thats all i am getting
this window appears and it goes nowhere

Comment: its like it is loading but it never starts

Comment: use the Genymotion emulator , you can find it here : https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Update your Android Studio.Better change the configurations of your emulator as per your requirements. Or use Genymotion emulator it's pretty fast

Comment: if you are not using google play services in ur app Id also recommend Genymotion even though theres a way to install GP services but its much faster

Comment: thanks.   Genymotion is working great

Answer (score 0):

Check your hardware profile and see if you are using x86 system image. If not change it to x86, because x86 images run the fastest in emulator. This should solve your problem. Moreover, if you are using older versions of Android Studio, it would be better to update to the latest. Currently the latest one is 2.1.1. The emulator is much faster now. Some new features are also added. You can explore yourself. The build process is also superfast now with the **Instant Run**.